Conda python package installs in wrong place
I have created a pure python conda package called ssstack using conda build, but when I install it (from the local build directory) using:
conda create -n <env name> -c <path to local build> ssstack`

the python package and CLI executables get put in the wrong place. Instead of it putting the python package in:
<ENV_ROOT>/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ssstack

it incorrectly puts them in the root of the environment, i.e.:
<ENV_ROOT>/site-packages/ssstack

It also puts the python CLI scripts in the wrong place; instead of it being put in
<ENV_ROOT>/bin/ssstack

It ends up being left in:
<ENV_ROOT>/python-scripts/ssstack

Obviously, neither the python module or the CLI scripts can be found when using the environment.
It's almost like conda doesn't know that it is a python package, so doesn't put it under the lib/python3.xx directory.
Oddly, if I create a new environment with just a python installation first, then activate it and install the ssstack package in to the existing environment then everything gets put in the correct place, i.e.:
conda create -n ssstack_env python==3.12
conda activate ssstack_env
conda install -c <path to local build> ssstack  ## WORKS!

I can't for the life of me understand why the latter method works correctly, but not the former.
I've spent a lot of time searching for a reason, but have come up with nothing. Any advice will be gratefully recieved!
Here's my meta.yaml recipe for reference:
{% set name = "ssstack" %}
{% set version = "0.4.0" %}

package:
  name: "{{ name|lower }}"
  version: "{{ version }}"

source:
  path: ../../..

build:
  noarch: python
  number: 1
  script: {{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . -vv --no-deps --no-build-isolation


requirements:
  host:
    - pip
    - python>=3.8
    - setuptools
  run:
    - conda
    - conda-lock
    - packaging
    - pydantic
    - pyyaml
    - requests
    - tabulate
    - tqdm
    - typer


Check your condarc and the env variable CONDA_* for hints. My experience is that when you do not have standard things (at stndard places), conda will selectively select the settings, and things get weird. And things got then worse, because conda will put some thing in the wrong location (the default), and so other thing that worked will start not working.

@GiacomoCatenazzi - nothing untoward in my .condarc and the CONDA_* envs look as expected.

OK - after many frustrating hours I finally figured this out for myself.
The issue was that python was missing as a dependency in requirements: -> run:, i.e.:
requirements:
  run:
    - python

It appears that without this conda doesn't realise that it is a python package and doesn't put the site-packages and CLI scripts in the right place.
This must be a change in behaviour of conda at some point because AFAIK this recipe used to work fine.
P.S. the thing that alerted to me to this was the lack of a _py part to the build version of the generated conda package.
